# Why does this glClearColor statement stop Libgdx html5 from compiling?

Tags: java, android, html, libgdx

I am using Libgdx for the first time and wondering what is wrong with this GLClearColor statement:

```
 Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Color.BLACK.getRed(), Color.BLACK.getGreen(),
 Color.BLACK.getBlue(), Color.BLACK.getAlpha());
```

This does not compile on HTML5, however:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
```

Does work.  Why is that?

Comment: This does not compile? Or it just shows wrong colors?

Comment: you should attach the stacktrace to help us understand why it is not working

Comment: It did not compile.  The correct answer was that AWT was being used so it would not work on the HTML5 target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Color` class has not methods like `getRed()` or `getGreen()` - take a look at the [reference of Color](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Color.html).

Instead of this it has *public* fields like `r` or `g`. So you should use

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Color.BLACK.r, Color.BLACK.g, Color.BLACK.b, Color.BLACK.a);
```

You should always start with analysing stacktrace - I'm pretty sure that this info is there. Take a look at:

- [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

---

EDIT:

due to Big Tony.D comment - if you are using awt's Color class just use LibGDX's one

Comment: It wasn't specified which Color is he using. There are these method in java.awt.Color https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRed%28%29

Comment: yup that's true - then answer is to use LibGDX's one :)

Comment: Thank you.. that was the right answer.. AWT's was inadvertently being used in the tutorial I was following.. changing to .r .g .b and using libgdx's was correct.